# What language or format is this in?

Tags: php, database, string, wordpress, joomla

After looking at the Wordpress and Joomla database, I began to recognize strings in this format.  What is it, how does it work?

here's an example:

```
a:5:{s:13:"administrator";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Administrator";s:12:"capabilities";a:62:{s:13:"switch_themes";b:1;s:11:"edit_themes";b:1;
```

Comment: its serialize() array http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: you are correct.  It is a serialized array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that was [serialized string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) from an object or array.

Comment: Downvoted because there was no link at the time. It's very obviously some form of serialized string.

Answer (score 2):

It's a serialized array. Basically a string to be used by the [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions in PHP, the base language for wordpress and likely joomla though I have never worked with joomla myself.